# How do you delete Podfile.lock?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podfile-lock

Xcode recently updated and my code is giving this error in STPAPIClient.m:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending '__strong STPAPIResponseBlock _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^__strong)(__strong ResponseType, NSHTTPURLResponse *__strong, NSError *__strong)') to parameter of type 'void (^)(STPSource *__strong, NSHTTPURLResponse *__strong, NSError *__strong)'
```

Edit: I found podfile.lock, but every time I delete it and pod install, I check the project directory and Podfile.lock is still there. Does anyone know how to delete it? Thanks!

Comment: `Podfile.lock` is an output of `pod install`

Comment: Okay. So now I'm trying to delete Stripe from my podfile.lock, but when I do pod install, it reinstalls Stripe. How can I remove Stripe?

Comment: See https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Comment: Remove Stripe from the Podfile

Comment: thanks Paul and Rob!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never modify Podfile.lock directly. It's generated by `pod install`. If you want to remove a Pod, edit Podfile, delete the Pod you want, and rerun `pod install`.

Comment: If i deleted `podfile.lock` file, that makes an issue or it's normally?

Comment: Generally you should not delete the podfile.lock, but if you do, I believe rerunning `pod install` should fix it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have removed some packages and it is still showing in podfile.lock.

Just goto project/ios_directory in your terminal and run following command one by one.

=> `pod update`

=> `pod install`

Comment: `pod clean` didn't work for me. I ran `pod update` instead and it generated me a new podfile.lock and I was able to run `pod install` afterwards.